# How to update my input values in my dataframe in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

First of all, i'm newbie in shiny so forgive if this is a simple question. I would to update my input data at my dataset after press a button.

I have two text input (client id and client's incidences) and two selectors (Month First Payment and Month Second Payment) and I want to update my data using app shiny. I would like update my data once i'll press the button, and there is the problem. I don't know how to update the inputs in my dataset. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
client<-c("00001S000","00002S000","00003S000","00004S000","00005S000","00006S000","00007S000","00008S000","00009S000")
pagament_1 <- c("Gener","","Marc","Febrer","","","","Gener","")
pagament_2 <- c("Abril","","Maig","Febrer","","","","Marc","")
y<-data.frame(client,pagament_1,pagament_2)
y

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("CONTROL CLIENTS"),
   sidebarPanel((""),
                textInput("client","Codi Client:",""),
                selectInput("pagament_1","Pagament 1", choices = c("-",
                                                                   "Gener",
                                                                   "Febrer",
                                                                   "Marc",
                                                                   "Abril",
                                                                   "Maig",
                                                                   "Juny",
                                                                   "Juliol",
                                                                   "Agost",
                                                                   "Setembre",
                                                                   "Octubre",
                                                                   "Novembre",
                                                                   "Desembre")),
                selectInput("pagament_2","Pagament 2", choices = c("-",
                                                                   "Gener",
                                                                   "Febrer",
                                                                   "Marc",
                                                                   "Abril",
                                                                   "Maig",
                                                                   "Juny",
                                                                   "Juliol",
                                                                   "Agost",
                                                                   "Setembre",
                                                                   "Octubre",
                                                                   "Novembre",
                                                                   "Desembre")),
                textInput("incidencia","Escriu la incidencia:",""),
                actionButton("goButton","Actualitzar Client!")

),
      mainPanel((""),
                tableOutput("client"),
                dataTableOutput("df"),
                textOutput("client_"),
                textOutput("pag_1"),
                textOutput("pag_2"),
                textOutput("incidencia"),
                tableOutput("client_all"))

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$client_all <-renderTable(y) 
  output$client <- renderTable({
     stateFilter <- subset(y,y$client == input$client)
   })
  output$client_    <- renderText({paste("CODI CLIENT:",input$client)})
  output$pag_1      <- renderText(if(input$pagament_1 == "-"){
    print("PAGAMENT 1: Sense canvis")
  } else {paste("PAGAMENT 1:",input$pagament_1)})
  output$pag_2      <- renderText(if(input$pagament_2 == "-"){
    print("PAGAMENT 2: Sense canvis")
  } else {paste("PAGAMENT 1:",input$pagament_2)})
  output$incidencia <- renderText(if(input$incidencia == ""){
    print("INCIDENCIA: No s'ha modificat")
  } else { paste("INCIDENCIA MODIFICADA:",input$incidencia)})
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton,{
      head(y,input$pagament_1)
    })
  data <- eventReactive(input$goButton == 1, {
    if (is.null(input$client)){
      return()
    }
    nr<- data.table(col1=input$client, col2=input$pagament_1, col3=input$pagament_2,
                     col4 = Sys.time(), col5 = input$incidencia)
    y <<-rbind(y,nr)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This is not clear to me: *"update input values"* sounds like `shiny::updateSelectInput` (et al), while *"in my dataframe"* sounds like your data either (1) needs to be reactive, or (2) needs to be over-written out-of-scope with `<<-` (instead of `<-`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some general misconceptions how to pass data in Shiny:

```
y <<-rbind(y,nr)
```

I guess you want to `rbind` this data to the dataframe you created on top. However it does not work this way. You create the second dataframe inside an `eventReactive` statement. Think about this as an own world. The "global" world does not know about what happened inside the reactive world, this is why you can not pass a data.frame created inside a `reactive` or `eventReactive` statement to the "outside world".

What you have to do is this something like this:

```
data <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if (is.null(input$client)){
        return()
    }
    nr<- data.table(col1=input$client, col2=input$pagament_1, col3=input$pagament_2,
                    col4 = Sys.time(), col5 = input$incidencia)
    y <-rbind(y,nr)
    y
})
```

You create this new data.frame or data.table by clicking the button, but never use a `<<-` operator here. When you click the button, R creates a promise called `data`, like a normal variable in R.

```
output$client <- renderTable({
    stateFilter <- subset(data(),y$client == input$client)
})
```

The promise object you created has to be passed to a **Reactive Endpoint**. This is the place where it gets rendered. You have to call the promise like a normal function by writing `data()`, not just `data`.

This is how you pass data you manipulated from one place to another. However your code has some errors, so I can not directly fix it (you try to rbind data with 5 columns to a data.frame with less columns), but you get an idea how to change your code :-)